# How to use subdomain like url instead with port number in laravel-echo-server host using docker and kubernetes?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, kubernetes

We are developing a laravel application using docker and kubernetes. While I am handling docker part and other guy handles kubernetes part.

Site was made live but other developer asked me to provide a code to use laravel-echo-server's host url as `ws.example.com` instead of `example.com:6001`.

Since port 6001 is used by echo server, I had created a `docker-composer.yml` its contents are as follows:

```
.
.
.
# Laravel Echo Server
  laravel-echo-server:
        build:
          context: ./docker_files/laravel-echo-server
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: bns_echo_server

        volumes:
          - ./docker_files/laravel-echo-server/laravel-echo-server.json:/var/www/laravel-echo-server.json:ro
        depends_on:
          - app
          - webserver
        ports:
          - "6001:6001"
        links:
          - redis
        networks:
          - app-network
.
.
.
```

its corresponding Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM node:alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
#WORKDIR /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /var/www

RUN apk add --update \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY laravel-echo-server.json /var/www/laravel-echo-server.json

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start", "--force" ]
```

and the `laravel-echo-server.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://webserver",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "123",
            "key": "123"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*.*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

`authHost` is `http://webserver` as webserver is the container name of `nginx`

Please guide us how can we achieve this goal ?

Comment: If you have Nginx or other webserver just make a proxy of 6001 to ws.example.com.

Comment: Could you post `YAML` definition of your `Deployment`. From the Kubernetes perspective you can run a `Deployment` with your `app` and use a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to specify how the app can be reached.